# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:colorPrimary' with value '@android:colors/blue'). 2

Tags: android, xamarin

In my Colors.xml, I declare blue color as follows

#375D81

Here's a link for my [Styles.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkDAL.png)

Comment: where is your styles.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@colors/blue</item>

Answer (score 0):

Try to define this color in colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ...
<color name="myBlue">#375D81</color>
</resources>
```

and in styles.xml reference it:

```
<item name="...">@color/myBlue</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

it thows this **No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:colorPrimary' with value '@android:colors/blue').** error beacuse there is no such resouce that match `@android:colors/blue`

you need to create a color resouce in your res/values/color.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   // your all colors
    <color name="myBlue">#ff00ff</color>
</resources>
```

than you can use this color in res/values/style.xml in your theme

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <resources>
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar"> 
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> 
  <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item> 
  <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color//blue</item> 
</style>
```

**ask me in case of any query**

Comment: How do I add icons in GridView?

Comment: i didn't get you my friend

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. I just wanted to ask a question but i have to wait for 3 days. 

I have this error when I want to create navigation bar in Xamarin Android.






'Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout' to type 'Android.Support.Design.Widget.NavigationView'.

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin while working on .xml or .axml files we need to clean and rebuild solution every time because of Android check resource Ids for controls at every time.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <resources>
  <style name="button_text" >
  <item name="android:layout_width" >fill_parent</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height" >wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:textColor" >#ffffff</item>
  <item name="android:gravity" >center</item>
  <item name="android:layout_margin" >3dp</item>
  <item name="android:textSize" >30dp</item>
  <item name="android:textStyle" >bold</item>
  <item name="android:shadowColor" >#000000</item>
  <item name="android:shadowDx" >1</item>
  <item name="android:shadowDy" >1</item>
  <item name="android:shadowRadius" >2</item>
</style>
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/style_a_button/